# Will Brew MP Run without Sourcery G++ ARM Compiler?

Tags: g++, gnu, brew-framework, brewmp

can I compile & run  Brew MP Applications without Sourcery G++ ARM Compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can compile and run Brew MP application without an ARM compiler as long as you're just developing for the Brew MP Simulator

In order to run Brew MP applications on the simulator you will need a compiler that can generate X86 binaries. You can use Sourcery G++/X86 or Visual Studio/Express to do this.

To run the application on a device you will need an ARM compiler. You can use a GNU based compiler such as Sourcery G++ ARM compiler, a commercial ARM compiler, or any compatible ARM compiler for this purpose. But not all compilers are tested and supported.

Comment: No, the tools plugins also supports the commercial Sourcery compiler and various commercial ARM compilers if you use those. Were you looking for something different?

Comment: but why Qulacomm has recommended to use sourcery Lite edition ARM?
May I Know about this? pls see the URL https://brewmobileplatform.qualcomm.com/devnet/multiplatform_sdk.jsp

Comment: The Lite edition is a free version for folks looking for a free gcc based compiler. The same way, we also recommend VS as an alternative. Recommendations are not musts, they're just suggestions for options that we've tried and know work. Does that help?